# Redis: Remove a specific value from all sets

Tags: redis

I have a program that stores data in Redis. There are an arbitrary number of sets stored in keys under the namespace "foo", i.e. `keys foo:*` will return a list of keys of sets. I want to remove the string "bar" from all sets that contain it within the namespace. Essentially (this is in Ruby):

```
redis.keys("foo:*").each do |key|
  redis.srem(key, "bar")
end
```

Due to the use of `keys`, which is not intended for production use, this is inefficient and not atomic. Is there any better way to remove "bar" from all the sets, given that I don't have the keys of the sets I want to operate on in advance?

I'd be okay with using a Lua script if that's the only way to do with atomicity and to make it performant.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this would be to have a reverse lookup from strings to sets.

- In the code that inserts a string into a set, you would also insert the set name into a set for that string.  For example, inserting string `bar` into set `foo:baz` would also cause an insertion of value `foo:baz` into set `foo:strings:bar` or something like that.

  If the set data already exists, you can run a one time backfill job by just iterating over each set and creating the string->set_name sets.
- Now that those sets are there, your code for removing a string from sets is something like:

  ```
  redis.smembers("foo:strings:#{string}").each do |set|    
    redis.srem(set, string)
  end
  ```

You are now no longer doing full table scan key lookups.